# Couldn't go bad vs. Wouldn't go bad

Tags: modal-verbs

> She kept milk in the fridge so that it couldn't go bad.

Is that sentence possible? Of course

> She kept milk in the fridge so that it wouldn't go bad.

is better.

But my students said, "She kept milk in the fridge so that it ***couldn't*** go bad."

Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Correct in what way? Grammatically? Semantically? Idiomatically? Of course, there's nothing wrong with the grammatical structure (compare: _He locked the horses in the barn so they couldn't get out._)

Comment: Thank you. I understand it has nothing wrong with the grammatical structure.
How about semantically?

Answer (score 1):

The natural choice here is **wouldn't**.

> If you keep milk in the fridge, it **will** stay fresh and **won't** go bad
>   quickly, as it **would** if left on the countertop.  I put the milk in the fridge as soon as I got home, so it **wouldn't** go sour.

When might you use **could not**, which means "unable to"?

To express disbelief or surprise:

This milk is sour.
-- It **couldn't** be. I just bought it this morning at the supermarket, and its sell-by date is three weeks from now, and I put it in the fridge as soon as I got home.

A paraphrase would be:

This milk is sour.
-- That's **impossible**. I just bought it...